# How to run a python script with 3 parameters in command line

Tags: python, command-line, parameters, ini

I got a task in the school without any database and program lines. My task is to write a run command in the command line with the following criteria.

I have a python script called (main.py) and 3 parameters in 3 different directories and files:
c:\old_data
c:\new_data
.ini file (which contains region's names)

How to run the main.py in a command line with these 3 parameters, choosing one region (FNL) from the .ini file?

I did this:
python c:\tool\main.py c:\old_data c:\new_data

Is it a good start?
Thanks!

Comment: Show us more of what you've tried, especially a bit of code. If you've not got that far yet, maybe look into https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html or https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv as good places to start

Comment: read about configparser library and argument parsing in python, and pass path/name of .ini file as an input in your main.py script and read .ini file and use data in your script.

Comment: Do you know what is argv? If you were given task to use command line arguments, you should know it or have it mentioned somewhere in resources you were given. `from sys import argv`